# align* and wrapping command

Tags: math-mode, align

For school we have to deliver all math with double lines under the result.

I have made a command that makes this easy. It looks like this:

```
\newcommand*{\uul}[1]{
\underline{\underline{#1}}
}
```

It works great, except when I use it with the align* environment. If there is a `&=` inside, like so:

```
\uul{x &= 14}
```

it throw up all kinds of errors. If I remove the `&` it works just fine.

I am guessing there is some problems arising from passing the content around, but is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Please supply us with a full working document (called a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv)) that we can copy-and-paste to replicate your problem.

Comment: The Q&D solution is to use \uul{x}&\uul{= 4}

Answer (score 5):

I think the easiest way would be to retrace the "final equation" using an overlapped `\phantom`, where you set the underlines (as in the third set of equations below). That overcomes the problem of spreading the function across the alignment marker `&`, which is not easy to do otherwise:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand*{\uul}[1]{\underline{\underline{#1}}}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
     x &= 5
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
     \text{\uul{$x$}} &\text{\uul{${}= 5$}}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
     x &= 5\llap{\uul{\phantom{$x=5$}}}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \\
       &\makebox[0pt][r]{\uul{$x$}}\text{\uul{${} = 5$}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

`\llap` is similar to `\makebox[0pt][r]` which provides a `l`eft over`lap` of stuff.